# возникла ошибка , при наведении на блоки

Tags: html, css

Я написал в css что при наведении на 4 блока с разным классом они меняли свой цвет , написал другому блоку что при наведении у него будет появляться бордюр ,но у него появляется бордюр сразу при загрузки сайта и при наведении на любой из четырёх блоков это бордюр пропадает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Где написали? Что за блоки? Легко исправить!

Comment: нужно исправить css-селекторы. Добавьте в вопрос, какие они у вас сейчас?

Answer (score 0):

Все работает :)

```css
.block{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: #45a163; /*Цвет блоков при начальной загрузки страницы*/
  margin: 1px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid transparent; /*Прозрачный бордер чтоб не прыгало*/
}
.block:hover{
  border: 2px solid black; /* Бордюр при навидении, псевдокласс HOVER */
  cursor:pointer;
}
.one:hover{
  background: #bad; /* Цвет при навидении на блок */
}
.two:hover{
  background: #f48024; /* Цвет при навидении на блок */
}
.three:hover{
  background: #07c;  /* Цвет при навидении на блок */
}
.four:hover{
  background: #ffeb3b;  /* Цвет при навидении на блок */
}
```

```html
<div class="block one"></div>
<div class="block two"></div>
<div class="block three"></div>
<div class="block four"></div>
```